# How to access environment variables from winrt

Tags: windows-runtime

Is there any subsitute of getenv function under WinRT?

Or maybe it's not possible to access environment variables at all?

Comment: Only an educated guess, but I don't believe you can do it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not possible to retrieve environment variables from a WinRT app. However, your app has a local, roaming, and temp folder available to it. Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current has all the root folders you need to create/read/delete files and folders in your app's folders.